# Derive curve and equation from points

Tags: curves

Sorry if this sounds confusing, but I have a set of points that I have displayed [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Hr4t.png)

What I want to do is to somehow get a curve to look something like [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmoT8.png) and to get the equation of that curve. How do I do this? Is there an easy way to do it by hand, or can I get a piece of software that does it? I have tried to make a trendline in excel, but the curve isn't very good. To me it looks like an upside down Gaussian function. Thanks

Comment: You need a nonlinear (curve-fitting) method, and the [R](https://www.r-project.org/) programming language is a powerful tool in that regard. See for example [Simple nonlinear least squares curve fitting in R](http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=5254) or [On curve fitting using R](http://davetang.org/muse/2013/05/09/on-curve-fitting/). Also, without having the data set in hand, it is hard to say which method will be the most accurate.

Comment: It actually depends on what you are doing and in what context this is being done. There are so many ways that the curve you may fit will be considered 'overfitted'. So you have to say in what context your question is coming from. If it is simply a set of points where an equation is to be identified, then there many functions that would satisfy this.

Comment: I am using to do do a geometric calibration of a thermal imaging camera. I just want the curve to roughly line up with the points so I can get an equation from it

Comment: @Weaam thanks for the suggestion